# How to capture different routes flow in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` for routing in my angular SPA.

I have a use case where one can reach a View (lets say View A) through route 1 or route 2. If user clicks on a button in View A, depending on which route user has come from to this view, need to perform different action - maybe redirect to route 3 (if from route1) or route 4 (if from route 2).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the event `$stateChangeStart`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
//Do whatever you want here
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current state name using `$state.current.name` and change state with `$state.go('...');`

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You can provide different controllers for the same view in different routes.

Besides, that controllers can be childs of one parent controller if you have some simiral logics.